# Reading sh_name from header will return one value everytime

Tags: c, linux, header, elf

Whenever isstatic32 is called, it will return STATIC even though the program is dynamically compiled. I have no idea what to do. I've tried everytime it detects .dynamic from sh_name, it adds 1 to a variable and if  the variable is > 1 it will return dynamic, but that didn't work. (won't let me post code here)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <elf.h>
#define DYNAMIC 1
#define STATIC 2        



static int isstatic32(FILE* fd, Elf32_Ehdr eh, Elf32_Shdr sh_table[])
{
static int i;
static int kek = 0;
static char* sh_str;
static char* buff;

buff = malloc(sh_table[eh.e_shstrndx].sh_size);

if(buff != NULL)
{
    fseek(fd, sh_table[eh.e_shstrndx].sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buff, 1, sh_table[eh.e_shstrndx].sh_size, fd);
}
sh_str = buff;

for(i=0; i<eh.e_shnum; i++)
{
    printf("%d", i);
    if(!strcmp(".dynamic", (sh_str + sh_table[i].sh_name)))
    {
        return DYNAMIC;
    }
}

return STATIC;

}


int main()
{

                FILE *fp = NULL;
                char* f;
                f = "/proc/self/exe";                   
                Elf32_Ehdr elf_header;
                Elf32_Shdr* sh_table;
                fp = fopen(f, "r");

                fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
                fread(&elf_header, 1, sizeof(Elf32_Ehdr), fp);
                sh_table = malloc(elf_header.e_shentsize*elf_header.e_shnum);
                fseek(fp, elf_header.e_shoff, SEEK_SET);
                fread(sh_table, 1, elf_header.e_shentsize*elf_header.e_shnum, fp);
                if(isstatic32(fp, elf_header, sh_table) == STATIC)
                {

                    printf("statically linked");

                }
                                    else
                {
                    printf("dynamic");
                }
                fp = NULL;
                f = NULL;



}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the code to be **in the question post**, not *linked*. Please, [edit] your question post and copy-paste the code into it. You may format the pasted code with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: There, code was removed from the pastebin and added onto here, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the program is dynamically compiled

The program *can't* be dynamically compiled (or rather, "dynamically compiled" means something totally different). What you mean is that the program is dynamically *linked*.

Wild guess: you compiled your code in 64-bit mode (because you are on a 64-bit system which defaults to 64-bit mode).

This:

```
Elf32_Ehdr elf_header;
```

is the wrong type to use if you are trying to determine whether 64-bit executable is statically linked or not.

P.S. There are many other bugs in your program as well.

P.P.S. Presence or absence of `.dynamic` is *not* correct way to determine whether the binary was statically or dynamically linked (sections aren't required, and can be completely stripped). You should look for `PT_DYNAMIC` program header instead.

P.P.P.S. You should learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).