# Is it possible to detect if a program has been dynamically linked via /proc/self/mem?

Tags: c, linux, header, elf

Via to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432841/5468463), I wanted to check if binaries were dynamically linked, by checking /proc/self/exe.
Now I am wondering if it's possible to detect if it is dynamically linked via /proc/self/mem, or any other tool in /proc/self, considering the program will be rendered useless if /exe doesn't exist.

Comment: Why do you want to use `/proc` for this? There are much easier ways. But it's not even clear why the program should know or care.

Comment: It's possible, but not reliably. What problem are you *actually* trying to solve? See http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Im trying to determine if a file has shares libraries, i know its possible to physically see if a file has shared libraries in /proc/PID/maps, but how would i see if it has any shared libraries in c?

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to determine if a file has shares libraries, i know its possible to physically see if a file has shared libraries in /proc/PID/maps, but how would i see if it has any shared libraries in c?

This *really* is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) then.

You can *trivially* determine whether you have shared libraries in the current process by using [dl_iterate_phdr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html).

```
The dl_iterate_phdr() function walks through the list of an
application's shared objects and calls the function callback once for
each object, until either all shared objects have been processed or
callback returns a nonzero value.
```